# Firefox taking a long time to open, how to speed it up?

Tags: debian, firefox

Firefox is taking a long time to open in Debian 8.8. Opera takes about two seconds but FF takes about 20. How is it possible to speed it up. Should I reinstall?

I have the following plugins:

AdBlock

That's all.

EDIT: reinstalled, same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I was using a version of Ad Block that was not compatible with my version of FF. Best to check here to see which versions are best

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/